# Save workflow as template not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, template

I need to save my reusable workflow as template in SharePoint Designer 2010. When I tried saving my workflow I'm getting this error.

**The server was unable to create your template. Please notify your server administrator.**

Comment: long name issue. check names of the workflow and/or InfoPath forms

Comment: hope following link helps you http://blog.scoreman.net/2012/10/error-when-saving-reusable-workflow-as-template/ http://www.oriolardevol.com/Article/Details/30

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to reproduce issue that you are facing. but Its working for me.

I have some suggestion for you

Do the workflow named with a long name or the specified path is very long?
SharePoint has limitation that fully qualified file name cannot more than 260 characters, and the directory name cannot more than 248 chars. If this is your problem, please rename the workflow to a shorter name.

Answer (score 2):

Inspect the disabled greyed out Control in browser.  Remove the disabled flag using just the browsers HTML. And close the browser. The control should be enabled. and the warning will go and you'll be able to Save the workflow.
[image]

Silly SharePoint Client Side Validation.